# Okta as SP (inbound SAML ) how to configure redirection URL after successful login

Tags: saml, okta

In my IDP initiated flow. I have created a saml response and sent to Okta's ACS URL Via post request I also sent relay state in hidden input element to ACS URL.

```
 <form method="post"
  action="{{url}}">
      <input type="hidden"
       name="SAMLResponse"
       value="{{saml_response}}" />

      <input type="hidden"
       name="RelayState"
       id="RelayState"
       value="{{relay_state}}" />
 </form>
 <script>    
  window.onload = function (){document.forms[0].submit(); }
 </script>
```

I am creating the SAML response and sending it to OKta ACS using the above code. The user is logging in successfully but after that, the user is redirected to https://org.okta.com/what-eve-i-have-passed-in-relaystate but I want to redirect the user to a diff domain other than okta.com.

I tried giving a full-fledged URL in the relay state but it didn't work. Am I missing any configuration in Okta?

Comment: Didn't get the part- you are posting SAMLResponse to OKTA in IdP Initiated flow? So isn't the case that you are initializing it :)  - also why would you post SAMLResponse? shouldn't it be SAMLRequest ? - sorry if I missed anything

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving the `SAMLResponse` to your `AssertionConsumerEndpoint` when no `RelayState` is passed? 
Based on the following [documentation](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/saml/#understanding-sp-initiated-sign-in-flow) from Okta

> A RelayState is an HTTP parameter that can be included as part of the
> SAML request and SAML response. In an SP-initiated sign-in flow, the
> SP can set the RelayState parameter in the SAML request with
> additional information about the request. A SAML IdP, after receiving
> the SAML request, takes the RelayState value and simply attaches it
> back as an HTTP parameter in the SAML response after the user has been
> authenticated. This way, when the round trip completes, the SP can use
> the RelayState information to get additional context about the initial
> SAML authentication request.

Okta ideally should not redirect directly to the `RelayState` after authentication.
You should receive back the `RelayState` as a request parameter along with `SAMLResponse` 
 to SP's `AssertionConsumerEndpoint`. From there, you can redirect to the url in `RelayState`.

Just to add, instead of url as the value, you can use some id. On receiving it back, extract the details against this id, and then redirect.

Comment: Sorry it is IDP initated flow.